# Table in AngularJS app with many "select" elements built with ng-repeat takes very long

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with variable number of records (could be up to hundreds) where its body is build with one `ng-repeat`.

Within each record, there are two input fields of type `select` where their contents is also built using `ng-repear` and the number of options for each is about 100.

This is working right now, except that it takes a lot of time for the page to be built (several seconds; I guess due to the large number of html records that AngularJS is adding to the DOM).

Here is an example of one of the `select`s:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="One_Source.Measuring_Method_Code">
    <option ng-selected="{{One_Method.Value == One_Source.Measuring_Method_Code}}"
            ng-repeat="One_Method in All_Collections.Parameters_Test_Methods"
            value="{{One_Method.Value}}"
            title="{{One_Method.Test_Method_Name}} | {{One_Method.Method_Internal_Name}}">
            {{One_Method.Value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Two questions:

1. Is there a simple way to speed up the page building process?
2. As shown in the example, each **option** in the list has a `title` clause displaying a detailed description of the option's meaning. How can I add a `title` to the `select` showing the description of the current value?

For the first question I was thinking about building the list of options for each `select` element only upon clicking on it, but I'm not sure if that would be the best way to do it.

Comment: You could try adding `ng-repeat="One_Method in All_Collections.Parameters_Test_Methods track by One_Method._id"`, track by adds internal caching, usually it's when adding and removing data it only adds and remove's what it needs to instead of re-drawing all html elements. If you don't have a unique key on the `One_Method` object, you can also use `track by $index`

Comment: Thank you @ShannonHochkins. Please see my comment to doublesharp's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [one time bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) so that Angular doesn't watch the value by prefixing it with `::`. It can also be more efficient to use `track by` in your `ng-repeat` if each row has a unique value, like an ID.

```
<option 
  ng-selected="{{One_Method.Value == One_Source.Measuring_Method_Code}}"
  ng-repeat="One_Method in All_Collections.Parameters_Test_Methods track by One_Method.id"
  value="{{::One_Method.Value}}"
  title="{{::One_Method.Test_Method_Name}} | {{::One_Method.Method_Internal_Name}}"
>
  {{::One_Method.Value}}
</option>
```

Comment: You could take this one step further by adding `ng-repeat="One_Method in ::All_Collections.Parameters_Test_Methods track by One_Method.id"`

Comment: Thank you doublesharp and @ShannonHochkins for your suggestions but, unfortunately, I see no noticeable improvement in the building of the page (which, by the way, if I comment out the `option` parts of the select it reacts almost instantly, say less than a second).

Comment: Hey soublesharp, please take a look and the answer I posted and let me know what you think about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't gain the performance you're expecting from @doublesharps's answer, you will have to implement one of the following:

1. You could build a custom list that has a 'load more' button which would destroy say the first '50' options and load the next 50.
2. A better option would be to turn this into an autocomplete, where the user searches for values.
3. Virtual repeat - Something angular material does really well, it constantly draw's and re-draws new elements based on the scroll position inside the element.

Other resources:

- http://blog.scalyr.com/2013/10/angularjs-1200ms-to-35ms/
- https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll
- http://klajd.github.io/angular-virtual-repeat/#/Home

Comment: Hey Shannon, please take a look and the answer I posted and let me know what you think about this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I found a ***PARTIAL SOLUTION*** that still needs to be polished but is quite promising.

During creation of the **page**, I do not make use of `ng-repeat` for the options but instead deploy a single option with the value received for the field from the database (if any, otherwise the select element is left blank).

When the user clicks on the select element a `$scope` function is invoked that checks the number of options within the select element and, if less or equal to 1, the inner HTML of this select element is re-generated and deployed.

Though clicking on all these select in the page will take (accumulative) a comparable time as when built upon load, this time is distributed over several events (the user clicking on all the select elements) and hence it is not perceived by the user.

Now, by **polishing** I mean that there is a strange behavior. In order to see the generated list of options, I need to click on the select twice. Will keep investigating this and post the solution (hoping I find one).

Comment: This should result in a better user experience because they aren't all generated before the page is displayed but the overall performance is similar. If it works it works though!

Comment: Well @doublesharp, as stated it **almost** work. The issue is that the first click event serves to populate the select list and then it shows it strangely. Only the second and subsequent clicks on that particular select show it as needed. I don't really know how to resolve this. Any ideas?

Comment: Rendering a select list with 100 elements shouldn't be that big of a deal - did you try using [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) with `track by` and the one way bindings I suggested? Are you sure the lag isn't caused by the application fetching the values for `All_Collections`?

Comment: I'm using [`oi-select`](https://tamtakoe.github.io/oi.select/) in an application with thousands of values and autocompleted.